# Search for matching XML elements from sequence using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I tried to write query `//*[contains(//*/@*[name() != 'id'], ./@id)]` but was unlucky.
Part of a query `//*/@*[name() != 'id']` finds sequence of attribute values and I want to find elements from this sequence which contains `./@id` but function `contains` can't operate with sequence and I don't know how to iterate through elements in sequence in XPath (I need to use only XPath).

How can I solve this?

Any help appritiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `contains()` check on individual attribute which name isn't equal 'id'. The following XPath will return element where at least one of the attribute pass the 'contains' check :

```
//*[@*[name() != 'id' and contains(., ../@id)]]
```

demo: [link1](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/b_vLG6646), [link2](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/015a8c61f853773c42087df9155038e9)

Comment: It helped me to think in the different direction and I solved the problem.